# How hazelcast determine the local member?

Tags: hazelcast

How hazelcast determine its local member. I have an application that runs in two different regions. one hazelcast member is in one region other is in another region. I have configured hazelcast to back up its member to another member. and I am allowing reading from the local member. but I want to know how hazelcast picks up the local member to make sure cross-region latency issue. or is there any way to set local member for an application?

Answer (score 0):

See [Hazelcast Anti-patterns, no.3](https://hazelcast.com/blog/hazelcast-anti-patterns/), trying to span two geographically distant sites with one cluster will cause you problems.

It's not specific to Hazelcast, clustering that uses synchronous communication requires *consistently fast* networking. If your sites are far enough apart that latency is noticeable, as your question implies, it'll break.

For two sites that are far enough apart, you need two clusters.

Comment: The regions are very close and the latency delay is around 5ms. which is completely acceptable for our application. our write ratio is very low. going for the two clusters is the best solution but replication between clusters is an enterprise feature.